# Скользащее меню и позиция по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, css, css3

В меню есть 2 скрипта.

Один скрипт при нажатии на кнопку меню скролит окно браузера к соответствующему блоку, а так же присваивает класс **active** выбранной кнопке меню *li*.

Второй скрипт плавно подчеркивает пункты меню при наведении зеленой линией. При загрузке страницы подчеркивается кнопка *li* которой задан класс **active** а уже от нее подчеркивающая линия перемещается при наведении.

Проблема в том, что выбранный пункт меню, которому задан класс **active** при загрузке страницы, он для второго скрипта так и остается подчеркнутым по умолчанию даже если класс **active** будет уже на другой кнопке.

Возможно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при скороле нижняя скользящая линия меняла свою позицию по умолчанию так же как и красная полоса сверху в примере. То есть, чтобы начальная координата зеленой линии всегда была на кнопке **active** как это делает красная линия, а не только при первой загрузке

Или подскажите альтернативу скользящей линии, которая бы работала таким образом.

```js
// первый скрипт
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
   
   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
   
   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});

// второй скрипт

$(document).ready(function(){
 
    var nav_wrap = $(".sliding-menu"),
        elem_width,
        elem_left_offset,
        elem_parent,
        slider_line;
     
    $(document).ready(function(){
 
        nav_wrap.each(function(){
            $(this).append('<li class="sliding-line"></li>');
 
            var start_elem_width = 0;
            var start_elem_offset = 0;
            var active_elem = $(this).find(".active");
 
            if(active_elem.length){
                start_elem_width = active_elem.outerWidth();
                start_elem_offset = active_elem.position().left;
            }
 
            $(this).find(".sliding-line").css({
                "width": start_elem_width + "px",
                "left": start_elem_offset + "px"
            })
            .data("width", start_elem_width)
            .data("left", start_elem_offset);
        });
 
    });
 
    nav_wrap.find("li a").hover(function(){
 
        elem_parent = $(this).parent();
        elem_width = elem_parent.outerWidth();
        elem_left_offset = $(this).position().left;
        slider_line = elem_parent.siblings(".sliding-line");
        slider_line.stop().animate({
            "width": elem_width + "px",
            "left": elem_left_offset + "px"
        });
 
    }, function(){
 
        slider_line.stop().animate({
            "width": slider_line.data("width") + "px",
            "left": slider_line.data("left") + "px"
        });
           
    });
 
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 6000px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  margin-top: 500px;
}

#top-menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#top-menu li {
    float: left;
}

#top-menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 25px 7px 25px;
    width: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    transition: .5s all ease-out;
    border-top: 3px solid white;
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#top-menu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#top-menu .active {
border-top: 1px solid red;  
}


div {
  height: 1000px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}



.sliding-line {
    height: 2px; /* Задаем высоту нашей "скользящей" полоске */
    background: #6da047; /* Задаем цвет для "скользящей" полоски */
    position: absolute; /* Позиционируем полоску абсолютным образом */
    bottom: -2px; /* Смещаем ее вниз на 2 пикселя. Здесь, как правило, задается значение эквивалентное высоте полоски, но только со знаком минус */
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top-menu" class="sliding-menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Top</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#baz">Baz</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="foo">Foo</div>


<div id="bar">Bar</div>


<div id="baz">Baz</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать например так (изменена вторая функция в hover):

```js
// первый скрипт
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
   
   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
   
   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});

// второй скрипт

$(document).ready(function(){
 
    var nav_wrap = $(".sliding-menu"),
        elem_width,
        elem_left_offset,
        elem_parent,
        slider_line;
     
    $(document).ready(function(){
 
        nav_wrap.each(function(){
            $(this).append('<li class="sliding-line"></li>');
 
            var start_elem_width = 0;
            var start_elem_offset = 0;
            var active_elem = $(this).find(".active");
 
            if(active_elem.length){
                start_elem_width = active_elem.outerWidth();
                start_elem_offset = active_elem.position().left;
            }
 
            $(this).find(".sliding-line").css({
                "width": start_elem_width + "px",
                "left": start_elem_offset + "px"
            })
            .data("width", start_elem_width)
            .data("left", start_elem_offset);
        });
 
    });
 
    nav_wrap.find("li a").hover(function(){ 
        elem_parent = $(this).parent();
        elem_width = elem_parent.outerWidth();
        elem_left_offset = $(this).position().left;
        slider_line = elem_parent.siblings(".sliding-line");
        slider_line.stop().animate({
            "width": elem_width + "px",
            "left": elem_left_offset + "px"
        }); 
    }, function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var active = $('.active', nav_wrap);
            slider_line.stop().animate({
                "width": active.width() + "px",
                "left": active.position().left + "px"
            });
        }, 500);
           
    });
 
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 6000px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  margin-top: 500px;
}

#top-menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#top-menu li {
    float: left;
}

#top-menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 25px 7px 25px;
    width: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
    transition: .5s all ease-out;
    border-top: 3px solid white;
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#top-menu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#top-menu .active {
border-top: 1px solid red;  
}


div {
  height: 1000px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}



.sliding-line {
    height: 2px; /* Задаем высоту нашей "скользящей" полоске */
    background: #6da047; /* Задаем цвет для "скользящей" полоски */
    position: absolute; /* Позиционируем полоску абсолютным образом */
    bottom: -2px; /* Смещаем ее вниз на 2 пикселя. Здесь, как правило, задается значение эквивалентное высоте полоски, но только со знаком минус */
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top-menu" class="sliding-menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Top</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#baz">Baz</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="foo">Foo</div>


<div id="bar">Bar</div>


<div id="baz">Baz</div>
```

Но есть баги, тк `.active` а вас добавляется не сразу после перехода. Красный бегунок стоит сделать по аналогии с зеленым отдельным элементом.

Comment: Спасибо. Почти то что надо, но срабатывает только при клике на пункты меню, а при прокрутке ничего расположение зеленой линии не меняется пока мышкой не наведешь на активный пункт. Красную линию я для примера добавил она не нужна вообще

Answer (score 0):

в конец 1 скрипта, добавлено установка координат возвращения на активный пункт.

```js
// первый скрипт
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
  topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
  topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 15,
  // All list items
  menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
  // Anchors corresponding to menu items
  scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) {
      return item;
    }
  });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e) {
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
    offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - topMenuHeight + 1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Get container scroll position
  var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;

  // Get id of current scroll item
  var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
      return this;
  });
  // Get the id of the current element
  cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
  var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

  if (lastId !== id) {
    lastId = id;
    // Set/remove active class
    var act = menuItems
      .parent().removeClass("active")
      .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("active");
    act.siblings(".sliding-line")
      .data({
        "width": act.outerWidth(),
        "left": act.position().left
      })

  }

});

// второй скрипт

$(document).ready(function() {

  var nav_wrap = $(".sliding-menu"),
    elem_width,
    elem_left_offset,
    elem_parent,
    slider_line;

  $(document).ready(function() {

    nav_wrap.each(function() {
      $(this).append('<li class="sliding-line"></li>');

      var start_elem_width = 0;
      var start_elem_offset = 0;
      var active_elem = $(this).find(".active");

      if (active_elem.length) {
        start_elem_width = active_elem.outerWidth();
        start_elem_offset = active_elem.position().left;
      }

      $(this).find(".sliding-line").css({
          "width": start_elem_width + "px",
          "left": start_elem_offset + "px"
        })
        .data("width", start_elem_width)
        .data("left", start_elem_offset);
    });

  });

  nav_wrap.find("li a").hover(function() {

    elem_parent = $(this).parent();
    elem_width = elem_parent.outerWidth();
    elem_left_offset = $(this).position().left;
    slider_line = elem_parent.siblings(".sliding-line");
    slider_line.stop().animate({
      "width": elem_width + "px",
      "left": elem_left_offset + "px"
    });

  }, function() {

    slider_line.stop().animate({
      "width": slider_line.data("width") + "px",
      "left": slider_line.data("left") + "px"
    });

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 6000px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  margin-top: 500px;
}
#top-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#top-menu li {
  float: left;
}
#top-menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 25px 7px 25px;
  width: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
  transition: .5s all ease-out;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#top-menu a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
#top-menu .active {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
div {
  height: 1000px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.sliding-line {
  height: 2px;
  /* Задаем высоту нашей "скользящей" полоске */
  background: #6da047;
  /* Задаем цвет для "скользящей" полоски */
  position: absolute;
  /* Позиционируем полоску абсолютным образом */
  bottom: -2px;
  /* Смещаем ее вниз на 2 пикселя. Здесь, как правило, задается значение эквивалентное высоте полоски, но только со знаком минус */
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top-menu" class="sliding-menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Top</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#baz">Baz</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="foo">Foo</div>


<div id="bar">Bar</div>


<div id="baz">Baz</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но при прокрутке активный пункт меню подчеркивается только если на него навести мышкой. А если клацнуть на какой-то пункт и сразу убрать мышку, то линия начинает плыть к цели и останавливается на том пункте, мимо которого проезжала в тот момент когда мышку убрали с области меню. Я так понимаю это из-за задержки. Можно её убрать лишь бы линия правильно срабатывала.